# How can I check memory usage for each cPanel account?

Tags: cpanel, vps, linux, usage-data, centos

Currently I have 4 cPanel accounts running on my VPS. I need to check the memory (RAM) usage for each account on the VPS to identify which of them is using high resources in order to ban. I opened the "Daily Process Log" in WHM but it is not showing the username or which accounts exactly uses resources.

WHM displayes the following under the "User" column:
root, nobody, mysql, dovenull, dovecot, mailnull, mailman, sshd, named, DELAYED, leechprotect, eximstats

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access try this

```
TOTAL=$(free | awk '/Mem:/ { print $2 }')
for USER in $(ps haux | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    ps hux -U $USER | awk -v user=$USER -v total=$TOTAL '{ sum += $6 } END { printf "%s %.2f\n", user, sum / total * 100; }'
done
```

See [this link  from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214315/how-to-find-user-memory-usage-in-linux) for more information